# Using bash, how do you make a classpath out of all files in a directory?

Tags: java, bash, file, directory, classpath

This will be a ***really*** simple freebie for a bash guru:

**Question**

Using bash, how do you make a classpath out of all files in a directory?

---

**Details**

Given a directory:

```
LIB=/path/to/project/dir/lib
```

that contains nothing but *.jar files such as:

```
junit-4.8.1.jar
jurt-3.2.1.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
mockito-all-1.8.5.jar
```

I need to create a colon-separated classpath variable in the form:

```
CLASSPATH=/path/to/project/dir/lib/junit-4.8.1.jar:/path/to/project/dir/lib/jurt-3.2.1.jar:/path/to/project/dir/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/path/to/project/dir/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar
```

Some seudo-code that nearly expresses the logic I'm looking for would be along the lines of:

```
for( each file in directory ) {
   classpath = classpath + ":" + LIB + file.name
}
```

What is a ***simple*** way to accomplish this via bash script?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

**New Answer**
*(October 2012)*

There's no need to manually build the classpath list. Java supports a convenient wildcard syntax for directories containing jar files.

```
java -cp "$LIB/*"
```

(Notice that the `*` is *inside* the quotes.)

Explanation from `man java`:

> As a special convenience, a class path element containing a basename of * is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension `.jar` or `.JAR` (a java program cannot tell the difference between the two invocations).
>
> For example, if directory foo contains `a.jar` and `b.JAR`, then the class path element `foo/*` is expanded to a `A.jar:b.JAR`, except that the order of jar files is unspecified. All jar files in the specified directory, even hidden ones, are included in the list. A classpath entry consisting simply of `*` expands to a list of all  the  jar  files  in  the  current directory. The `CLASSPATH` environment variable, where defined, will be similarly expanded. Any classpath wildcard expansion occurs before the Java virtual machine is started — no Java program will ever see unexpanded wildcards except by querying the environment.

---

**Old Answer**

#### Good

Simple but not perfect solution:

```
CLASSPATH=$(echo "$LIB"/*.jar | tr ' ' ':')
```

There's a slight flaw in that this will not handle file names with spaces correctly. If that matters try this slightly more complicated version:

#### Better

```
CLASSPATH=$(find "$LIB" -name '*.jar' -printf '%p:' | sed 's/:$//')
```

This only works if your find command supports `-printf` (as GNU `find` does).

If you don't have GNU `find`, as on Mac OS X, you can use `xargs` instead:

```
CLASSPATH=$(find "." -name '*.jar' | xargs echo | tr ' ' ':')
```

#### Best?

Another (weirder) way to do it is to change the field separator variable `$IFS`. This is very strange-looking but will behave well with all file names and uses only shell built-ins.

```
CLASSPATH=$(JARS=("$LIB"/*.jar); IFS=:; echo "${JARS[*]}")
```

Explanation:

1. `JARS` is set to an array of file names.
2. `IFS` is changed to `:`.
3. The array is echoed, and `$IFS` is used as the separator between array entries. Meaning the file names are printed with colons between them.

All of this is done in a sub-shell so the change to `$IFS` isn't permanent (which would be baaaad).

Comment: Thanks for your response. The simple version works perfectly. The *better* solution fails, for me, because *printf* is not a valid option for my find command (maybe I need to update bash? using 3.2.48 on this machine). The *best* option worked perfectly. Of course, neither the 'good' nor the 'best' option escape the spaces in file names, which is fine for me since there are none.

Comment: @gmale - The better and best options will accommodate spaces if you also quote CLASSPATH when you use it, as in `java -cp "$CLASSPATH"`

Comment: The "Best" is indeed best.  The "better" one doesn't handle jar file names with a space.

Comment: I think the most idiomatic solution is `CLASSPATH=$(find "$LIB" -name '*.jar'|paste -sd: -)`. Then you don't need this "weird" array bashism or GNU `find`. (I use an explicit `-` input parameter here to make it also work for BSD `paste`)

Comment: If you don't want `CLASSPATH` set if the `$LIB` directory contains no jars, you can first run `shopt -s nullglob`.

Comment: Can I use the same way if I have multiple directories having jar files in them ?

Comment: @AkashMahajan Sure. Write `java -cp 'lib1/*:lib2/*:lib3/*'`.

Answer (score 9):

```sh
for i in $LIB/*.jar; do
    CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$i
done
CLASSPATH=`echo $CLASSPATH | cut -c2-`
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I cut/paste this and it ran perfectly. It's a good example of using a for loop to accomplish something like this.

Comment: What does the `-c2-` param to cut do? I thought it might be `-c2 -` squished together, but that gives different results. If I omit the cut altogether I get the same results. What's it there for?

Comment: This is a good answer for non-bash shell environments that might not have `xargs` or the `-printf` option on `find`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another variation:

```
printf -v CLASSPATH "$LIB/%s:" *.jar; CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH%:}
```

`printf -v` is somewhat like `sprintf`. The brace expansion removes the extra colon from the end.

Comment: Needs to be `printf -v CLASSPATH "$LIB/%s" *.jar`.  Good call on the trailing colon, I had to look it up to see if it makes a difference and apparently it does, it's a valid NUL directory which causes the current directory to be searched (which may or may not be desirable).

Comment: @SeigeX: I made the change you suggested. I originally based my answer on "all files in a directory" and "contains nothing but *.jar files" in the question, but it pays to be selective.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I cut/paste & run this, I get a classpath delimited by spaces, instead of colons. I have no idea why. Other than that, it works well.

Comment: @gmale: I'm not able to reproduce that. Check to see if `IFS` has a value other than its default (space tab newline), but that shouldn't affect this. If you do `printf "%s:\n" *.jar` do you see any spaces? What about `printf '[%s]\n' "$LIB"`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Bestest

*Everything* is better with `awk` =)

```
CLASSPATH=$(awk '$0=lib"/"FILENAME' ORS=":" lib=$LIB *.jar)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I cut/paste that in and it generates the error `awk: can't open file *.jar`. So I removed the *.jar (since all files are jars in the lib directory) and the script just hangs as though awaiting input. I tried several other tweaks but I don't know enough about awk to fix it.