# Setting classPath inside Linux Script

Tags: linux

I wrote a simple Linux Script this way

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_20
export PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_20/bin
LIB_DIR=/home/praveen/lib

export CLASSPATH=.:$LIB_DIR/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:$LIB_DIR/log4j-1.2.8.jar

 java -cp $CLASSPATH com.test.Sample
```

**===============================================================================**

The above script  was working fine .

But when i tried for the first time with this , it was giving an error

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_20
export PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_20/bin
export CLASSPATH = /home/praveen/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar: /home/praveen/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar

  java -cp $CLASSPATH com.test.Sample
```

**As you can observe the only difference between these two scripts  is that , in the below script  on to the class path , i am not including the current directory path ( .)**

Please let me know , why this will not work this way ??

Comment: What error do you get? And where do you run this script from, are there are any class or JAR files present in the same directory from where you are running the script?

Comment: Related: [Using bash, how do you make a classpath out of all files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4729863/320399)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use:

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/praveen/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:/home/praveen/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar
```

rather than:

```
export CLASSPATH = /home/praveen/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar: /home/praveen/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar
```

You can't put spaces in between the variable name and the equals sign in shell scripting.

Answer (score 2):

You should not put any spaces in when you are setting variable, not even spaces around '=', it should be:

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/praveen/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:/home/praveen/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar
```

If you have spaces in one of the elements use single or double quotations e.g.:

```
MY_VAR1=' variable with spaces'
MY_VAR2=variable_without_spaces
export MY_VAR3="${MY_VAR1}${MY_VAR2}"
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one..:

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=...

cp=$(find lib -name "*.jar" -exec printf :{} ';')
if [[ -n "$CLASSPATH" ]]; then
    cp="$cp;CLASSPATH"
fi

"$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" -classpath "$cp" ...
```

Comment: Please explain what you are doing here.

Comment: the code block
    `cp=$(find lib -name "*.jar" -exec printf :{} ';')
    if [[ -n "$CLASSPATH" ]]; then
        cp="$cp;CLASSPATH"
    fi`
find all jar file in lib folder and append to variable cp, then use variable cp in java -classpath

Comment: Please explain what is being accomplished by putting comments.