# Spring No such bean when using * classpath

Tags: java, spring

using spring 2.5.6 for a standalone app.

i recently switched from using `java -cp dir/a.bar:dir/b.jar:dir/c.jar` to

```
java -cp dir/*
```

when i do this I get a

```
Could not process key 'dealerMasterSolrServer.baseURL' in PropertyOverrideConfigurer; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dealerMasterSolrServer' is defined
```

I see from the logs its trying the set the override before loading the bean, it only happens when i set the `*` classpath it works ok when i use individual jars. Any help is appreciated

Os
Redhat 6.1
2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64
Java version 1.6.0_34-b04

Comment: What version of Java? What OS? Etc

Answer (score 2):

The `dir/*` expands to `dir/a.jar dir/b.jar dir/c.jar`, i.e. you are missing the colons `:` that separate entries in the classpath.

Have a look at: [Using bash, how do you make a classpath out of all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729863/using-bash-how-do-you-make-a-classpath-out-of-all-files-in-a-directory) for a solution.