# strange behaviour : export CLASSPATH=$(JARS=(./lib/*.jar); IFS=:; echo "${JARS[*]}")

Tags: java, bash

```bsh
export CLASSPATH=$(JARS=(./lib/*.jar); IFS=:; echo "${JARS[*]}")
```

If I put this line in a `bash_script.sh` and do

```
chmod +x bash_script.sh
```

and then run

```
./bash_script.sh
```

it gives the error.

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")
```

How ever I am able to run this thing directly from the prompt and get the expected result.
as

```bsh
$ export CLASSPATH=$(JARS=(./lib/*.jar); IFS=:; echo "${JARS[*]}")
```

I was wondering what is the reason for this strange behaviour.

Comment: Does your script explicitly have a `#!/bin/bash` at the top? And what is your interactive command shell?

Comment: It works for me w/o errors either from command prompt or executing as script (albeit with no results).

Comment: adding #!/bin/bash at the top does make it work for me

Comment: Since it helped you, I added it as an answer.

Comment: Even if you put in a shebang line some people will still try to call your script with `sh bash_script.sh` so I suggest putting in a `set +o posix` in as well, to disable posix compliancy explicitely. Best way though is avoid the bashism and do a combination of `find` and `paste` to build the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your shell script. Array syntax `VAR=(...)` is a bash-ism. It won't work in plain sh (`#!/bin/sh`).

By the way, that looks like a line from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4729899/68587). If so, I encourage you to use my updated solution rather than this.

> There's no need to manually build the classpath list. Java supports a convenient wildcard syntax for directories containing jar files.
>
> ```
> java -cp "$LIB/*"
> ```
>
> [(read more)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4729899/68587)

Answer (score 1):

Add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line to force it to be run in the bash shell.