# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task from application

Tags: apache-spark

I have a problem with running spark application on standalone cluster. (I use spark 1.1.0 version).
I succesfully run master server by command:

```
bash start-master.sh
```

Then I run one worker by command:

```
bash spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://fujitsu11:7077
```

At master’s web UI:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

I see, that master and worker are running.

Then I run my application from Eclipse Luna. I successfully connect to cluster by command

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("spark://fujitsu11:7077", "myapplication");
```

And after that application works, but when program achieve following code:

```
 JavaRDD<Document> collectionRdd = sc.parallelize(list);
```

It's crashing with following error message:

```
 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 11, fujitsu11.inevm.ru):java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: maven.maven1.Document
 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:59)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.readObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
    org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:159)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
 Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1185)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1174)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

In shell I found:

```
14/11/12 18:46:06 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java"  "-cp" ";;D:\spark\bin\..\conf;D:\spark\bin\..\lib\spark-assembly-
1.1.0-hadoop1.0.4.jar;;D:\spark\bin\..\lib\datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.1.jar;D:\spar
k\bin\..\lib\datanucleus-core-3.2.2.jar;D:\spark\bin\..\lib\datanucleus-rdbms-3.
2.1.jar" "-XX:MaxPermSize=128m" "-Dspark.driver.port=50913" "-Xms512M" "-Xmx512M
" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "akka.tcp://sparkDriv
er@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50913/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "0" "fujitsu11.inevm.ru
" "8" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50892/user/Worker" "app-2014111
2184605-0000"
14/11/12 18:46:40 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20141112184605-0000/0
14/11/12 18:46:40 INFO ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-2014111218
4605-0000/0 interrupted
14/11/12 18:46:40 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
14/11/12 18:46:40 INFO Worker: Executor app-20141112184605-0000/0 finished with
state KILLED exitStatus 1
14/11/12 18:46:40 INFO LocalActorRef: Message [akka.remote.transport.ActorTransp
ortAdapter$DisassociateUnderlying] from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters] to
Actor[akka://sparkWorker/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtoco
l-tcp%3A%2F%2FsparkWorker%40192.168.3.5%3A50955-2#1066511138] was not delivered.
[1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with c
onfiguration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-
shutdown'.
14/11/12 18:46:40 INFO LocalActorRef: Message [akka.remote.transport.Association
Handle$Disassociated] from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters] to Actor[akka:/
/sparkWorker/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2
FsparkWorker%40192.168.3.5%3A50955-2#1066511138] was not delivered. [2] dead let
ters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration
settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
14/11/12 18:46:41 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkWorker
@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50892] -> [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50954
]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:5
0954]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sp
arkExecutor@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50954]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon
$2: Connection refused: no further information: fujitsu11.inevm.ru/192.168.3.5:5
0954
]
14/11/12 18:46:42 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkWorker
@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50892] -> [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50954
]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:5
0954]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sp
arkExecutor@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50954]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon
$2: Connection refused: no further information: fujitsu11.inevm.ru/192.168.3.5:5
0954
]
14/11/12 18:46:43 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkWorker
@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50892] -> [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50954
]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:5
0954]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sp
arkExecutor@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50954]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon
$2: Connection refused: no further information: fujitsu11.inevm.ru/192.168.3.5:5
0954
]
```

In logs:

```
14/11/12 18:46:41 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError    [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@fujitsu11:7077]     -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50913]:   Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50913]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with   [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50913]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection  refused: no further information: fujitsu11.inevm.ru/192.168.3.5:50913
]
14/11/12 18:46:42 INFO Master: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50913 got disassociated,   removing it.
14/11/12 18:46:42 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@fujitsu11:7077] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50913]: Error [Association failed with   [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50913]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with   [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50913]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection  refused: no further information: fujitsu11.inevm.ru/192.168.3.5:50913
]
14/11/12 18:46:43 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@fujitsu11:7077] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50913]: Error [Association failed with   [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50913]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with   [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@fujitsu11.inevm.ru:50913]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection  refused: no further information: fujitsu11.inevm.ru/192.168.3.5:50913
]
```

I googled a lot but I have no idea whats wrong...
I found a bit similar discussion here:

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/issues/187

But it doesn't solve my problem...

Somebody knows whats wrong?

Thank You.

Comment: Got the same error today. When I try the same from spark-shell, it works. Doesn't give any error. Running through maven throws ClassNotFound exception. Have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855368/spark-throws-classnotfoundexception-when-using-jars-option ( running using spark-submit ) ?

Comment: Thanks for quick response! No, I'll try your approach, thanks for advice! But it's pretty sad, that running from IDE throws exception...

Comment: Got it. The problem was with classpath. Use the first answer from this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven to create a fat jar. Then using spark-submit, run the application. For me it was something like this : 
./spark-submit --class "sandbox.Mllib.MllibTest" --master "spark://JPawade.local:7077" /Users/aditya.pawade/Projects/IntelliJ/Sandbox/target/sandbox-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Then it should run. Maybe there is a different solution. But this does work.

Comment: Thanks Man, You're amazing! I'll try and report about results!

Comment: I had to restart jupyter kernel and the problem was fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way to run it using IDE / Maven

1. Create a Fat Jar ( One which includes all dependencies ). Use Shade Plugin for this. Example pom :

> ```
> <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>2.2</version>
>     <configuration>
>         <filters>
>             <filter>
>                 <artifact>*:*</artifact>
>                 <excludes>
>                     <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
>                     <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
>                     <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
>                 </excludes>
>             </filter>
>         </filters>
>     </configuration>
>     <executions>
>         <execution>
>             <id>job-driver-jar</id>
>             <phase>package</phase>
>             <goals>
>                 <goal>shade</goal>
>             </goals>
>             <configuration>
>                 <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
>                 <shadedClassifierName>driver</shadedClassifierName>
>                 <transformers>
>                     <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
>                     <!--
>                     Some care is required:
>                     http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html
>                     -->
>                     <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
>                         <resource>reference.conf</resource>
>                     </transformer>
>                     <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
>                         <mainClass>mainClass</mainClass>
>                     </transformer>
>                 </transformers>
>             </configuration>
>         </execution>
>         <execution>
>             <id>worker-library-jar</id>
>             <phase>package</phase>
>             <goals>
>                 <goal>shade</goal>
>             </goals>
>             <configuration>
>                 <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
>                 <shadedClassifierName>worker</shadedClassifierName>
>                 <transformers>
>                     <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
>                 </transformers>
>             </configuration>
>         </execution>
>     </executions>
> </plugin>
> ```

2. Now we have to send the compiled jar file to the cluster. For this, specify the jar file in the spark config like this :

> SparkConf conf = new
>   SparkConf().setAppName("appName").setMaster("spark://machineName:7077").setJars(new
>   String[] {"target/appName-1.0-SNAPSHOT-driver.jar"});

3. Run mvn clean package to create the Jar file. It will be created in your target folder.
4. Run using your IDE or using maven command :

> mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="className"

This does not require spark-submit. Just remember to package file before running

If you don't want to hardcode the jar path, you can do this :

1. In the config, write :

> SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
>                               .setAppName("appName")
>                               .setMaster("spark://machineName:7077")
>                               .setJars(JavaSparkContext.jarOfClass(this.getClass()));

2. Create the fat jar ( as above ) and run using maven after running package command :

> java -jar target/application-1.0-SNAPSHOT-driver.jar

This will take the jar from the jar the class was loaded.

Comment: Man! On local machine works like a charm!! ( I used your second advice - created fat jar, updated SparkConf, and worker has started.) But when I'm trying to use the remote machine to connect to the master's one - I have the same error about classpath... How do You think - should I do something on the remote machine too, or maybe needs some another trick ? Thank You!

Comment: I don't know how it exactly works, but from what I have read, I think the driver program creates a server, to which all other cluster worker nodes connect and get the application jar. So you have 2 choices. 1. The jar files of your dependencies should be available in the classpath of worker nodes ( configured in the SCALA_CLASSPATH ), or it should be available with the driver program, with the workers having connectivity with the driver node. Can you explain in detail about your architecture ? I am not able to understand what is the remote machine ( worker/application ) and the general network

Comment: My master machine - is a machine, where I run master server, and where I launch my application. The remote machine - is a machine where I only run `bash spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://mastermachineIP:7077`. Both machines are in one local network, and remote machine succesfully connect to the master. (I see it in localhost:8080 on the master's one). Maybe I should set some settings in SparkConf? When I creating fat jar there was only `JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("spark://mastermachineIP:7077", "myapplication");`

Comment: And how are you running the application ? From the master server ? Using the jar ? Also, the fat jar must contain the jar files of your dependencies. When you create the fat jar, you must give specify the jars, then package it.

Comment: I run it from master server from IDE in debug mode.. Is it incorrect? Okay, I'll try to create application jar and run it... I remember, that were some problems with creating application jar, and at some point I run it from IDE.

Comment: But how are you finally planning to deploy it ? In the end, you will have to compile it, package it into a fat jar and then run it using java -jar right ? Can you try it this way ? If you are running it using IDE, you need to compile and package the application first, then specify the path of the jar in the SparkConf and then run it. I was able to run it this way in my system

Comment: Thanx Man I'll follow your advice and inform You about results!

Comment: Man! This problem I solved by giving equal location of Spark's home folder on both machines and setting in SparkConf following instruction - `.set("spark.home","path_to_spark");`

Comment: @dimson, can you detail what do you refer by giving equal location on both machines? Where do you specify that? What value do you assign? Did you require creating the jar or with these steps it´s not required?

Comment: I set SPARK_HOME in system variables on both machines with equal paths. Then on the off-chance I set SPARK_HOME in `spark-submit` and `spark-class` files. Finally I wrote `.set("spark.home","path_to_spark");` for SparkConf in program code of my application.

Comment: And yes, I created the jar.

Answer (score 12):

For the benefit of others running into this problem:

I faced an identical issue due to a mismatch between the spark connector and spark version being used. Spark was 1.3.1 and the connector was 1.3.0, an identical error message appeared:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
  Task 2 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost 
  task 2.3 in stage 0.0
```

Updating the dependancy in SBT solved the problem.

Comment: how do you update dependency in SBT and what is SBT?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' SBT is the [Scala Build Tool](http://www.scala-sbt.org/)

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same error message and in my case it was my rdd was empty and an aggregation task was attempted against it.

Listing this case here for the benefit of others running into this error message:
`Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 9 in stage 24.0 failed 4 times`

This advice in link provided below helped.
".. rdd is getting empty. The null pointer exception indicates that an aggregation task is attempted against of a null value. Check your data for null where not null should be present and especially on those columns that are subject of aggregation"
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/PySpark-failuer-spark-SparkException-Job-aborted-due-to/td-p/171147