# Spark spark-submit --jars arguments wants comma list, how to declare a directory of jars?

Tags: java, scala, jar, apache-spark, cluster-computing

In [Submitting Applications in the Spark docs, as of 1.6.0 and earlier](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management), it's not clear how to specify the --jars argument, as it's apparently not a colon-separated classpath not a directory expansion.

The docs say "Path to a bundled jar including your application and all dependencies. The URL must be globally visible inside of your cluster, for instance, an hdfs:// path or a file:// path that is present on all nodes."

> Question: What are all the options for submitting a classpath with
>   --jars in the spark-submit script in $SPARK_HOME/bin? Anything undocumented that could be submitted as an improvement for docs?

I ask because when I was testing --jars today, we had to explicitly provide a path to each jar:

```
/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit --class jpsgcs.thold.PipeLinkageData ---jars=local:/usr/local/spark/jars/groovy-all-2.3.3.jar,local:/usr/local/spark/jars/guava-14.0.1.jar,local:/usr/local/spark/jars/jopt-simple-4.6.jar,local:/usr/local/spark/jars/jpsgcs-core-1.0.8-2.jar,local:/usr/local/spark/jars/jpsgcs-pipe-1.0.6-7.jar /usr/local/spark/jars/thold-0.0.1-1.jar
```

We are choosing to pre-populate the cluster with all the jars in /usr/local/spark/jars on each worker, it seemed that if no local:/ file:/ or hdfs: was supplied, then the default is file:/ and the driver makes the jars available on a webserver run by the driver. I chose local, as above.

And it seems that we do not need to put the main jar in the --jars argument, I have not tested yet if other classes in the final argument (application-jar arg per docs, i.e. /usr/local/spark/jars/thold-0.0.1-1.jar) are shipped to workers, or if I need to put the application-jar in the --jars path to get classes not named after --class to be seen.

(And granted with Spark standalone mode using --deploy-mode client, you also have to put a copy of the driver on each worker but you don't know up front which worker will run the driver)

Comment: Wanted to provide a clear answer to this, per my comment and a response on Josh Rosen's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855368/spark-throws-classnotfoundexception-when-using-jars-option/24968221?noredirect=1#comment57212105_24968221

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this way it worked easily.. instead of specifying each jar with version separately..

```
#!/bin/sh
# build all other dependent jars in OTHER_JARS

JARS=`find ../lib -name '*.jar'`
OTHER_JARS=""
   for eachjarinlib in $JARS ; do    
if [ "$eachjarinlib" != "APPLICATIONJARTOBEADDEDSEPERATELY.JAR" ]; then
       OTHER_JARS=$eachjarinlib,$OTHER_JARS
fi
done
echo ---final list of jars are : $OTHER_JARS
echo $CLASSPATH

spark-submit --verbose --class <yourclass>
... OTHER OPTIONS
--jars $OTHER_JARS,APPLICATIONJARTOBEADDEDSEPERATELY.JAR
```

- #### Using `tr` unix command also can help like the below example.

  `--jars $(echo /dir_of_jars/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')`
- #### One parent directory and recrsive directorires (each dir have different jars) ... case

```
$(find /dir_of_jars -name '*.jar' -print0 | tr '\0' ',' | sed 's/,$//')
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround, [for Spark 1.6.1 and later, when available, the comma list requirement should be documented more directly](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management). I went ahead and accepted this. Just to be sure, this works as is? The line `OTHER_JARS=$eachjarinlib,$OTHER_JARS` doesn't need any quotes? I guess the shell is not going to expand that comma out and therefore takes it just to be a string, but it might be safer to double quote it? `OTHER_JARS="$eachjarinlib,$OTHER_JARS"`?

Comment: Jim, Yes doesn't need double quotes. This works(spark 1.3,1.5 versions) as it is.

Comment: this is another option which is simpler --jars $(echo /dir/of/jars/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')

Answer (score 0):

One way (the only way?) to use the --jars argument is to supply a comma-separated list of explicitly named jars.  The only way I figured out to use the commas was a StackOverflow answer that led me to look beyond the docs to the command line:

```
spark-submit --help
```

The output from that command contains:

```
 --jars JARS                 Comma-separated list of local jars to include on the driver
                              and executor classpaths.
```

Today when I was testing --jars, we had to explicitly provide a path to each jar:

```
/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit --class jpsgcs.thold.PipeLinkageData ---jars=local:/usr/local/spark/jars/groovy-all-2.3.3.jar,local:/usr/local/spark/jars/guava-14.0.1.jar,local:/usr/local/spark/jars/jopt-simple-4.6.jar,local:/usr/local/spark/jars/jpsgcs-core-1.0.8-2.jar,local:/usr/local/spark/jars/jpsgcs-pipe-1.0.6-7.jar /usr/local/spark/jars/thold-0.0.1-1.jar
```