# Spark SqlContext and Hbase: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/Bytes

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hbase

I am trying to access the Hive table in Spark which is created on top hBase table.

`sqlContext.sql("select * from dev.hive_habse_table")`

Eventhough I have included all the required jar, like this
`export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$(hbase classpath)`

and Initiated spark shell with Hive hbase handler in HDP 2.5 ( Spark 1.6.3)

```
  spark-shell --master yarn-client --conf spark.yarn.queue=uk --executor-cores 10 --executor-memory 20G --num-executors 15 --driver-memory 2G --jars hive-hbase-handler-1.2.1000.2.4.0.1-6.jar
```

I am still getting Below error. Could any one help?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/Bytes
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe.parseColumnsMapping(HBaseSerDe.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDeParameters.(HBaseSerDeParameters.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe.initialize(HBaseSerDe.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.AbstractSerDe.initialize(AbstractSerDe.java:53)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.initializeSerDe(SerDeUtils.java:521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:391)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializer(Table.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getCols(Table.java:605)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$getTableOption$1$$anonfun$3.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:347)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$getTableOption$1$$anonfun$3.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:342)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$getTableOption$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$getTableOption$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.liftedTree1$1(ClientWrapper.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.retryLocked(ClientWrapper.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.getTableOption(ClientWrapper.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientInterface$class.getTable(ClientInterface.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.getTable(ClientWrapper.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.lookupRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$2.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$OverrideCatalog$$super$lookupRelation(HiveContext.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$class.lookupRelation(Catalog.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$2.lookupRelation(HiveContext.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.getTable(Analyzer.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:309)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:309)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.(DataFrame.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:25)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:31)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:33)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:35)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:37)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:39)
    at $iwC$$iwC.(:41)
    at $iwC.(:43)
    at (:45)
    at .(:49)
    at .()
    at .(:7)
    at .()
    at $print()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.doLoadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.loadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:201)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 130 more
```

Comment: Can you define the jar(s) using `--jars` or `--packages` or similar when executing `spark-submit`? I think I've never seen `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` used with Spark.

Comment: can you try in this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35550151/647053) please see my answer there. I think jacek is also suggesting that.

Answer (score 0):

Please can you check these 2 options wheather working ?

1- try setting $HBASE_HOME/lib/* in --jars ?
2- try setting hbase classpath in the hadoop-env.sh file ?

Thanks