# How to append a resource jar for spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

My spark application depends on adam_2.11-0.20.0.jar, every time I have to package my application with adam_2.11-0.20.0.jar as a fat jar to submit to spark.

for example, my fat jar is myApp1-adam_2.11-0.20.0.jar,

It's ok to submit as following

```
spark-submit --class com.ano.adam.AnnoSp myApp1-adam_2.11-0.20.0.jar
```

It reported Exception in

> thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

org/bdgenomics/adam/rdd using --jars

```
spark-submit --class com.ano.adam.AnnoSp myApp1.jar --jars adam_2.11-0.20.0.jar
```

My question is how to submit using 2 separate jars without package them together

```
spark-submit --class com.ano.adam.AnnoSp myApp1.jar adam_2.11-0.20.0.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all jars in one folder and then do like below...

#### Option 1 :

I think Better way of doing this is

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--driver-class-path  $(echo /usr/local/share/build/libs/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') \
--jars $(echo /usr/local/share/build/libs/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')
```

in this approach, you wont miss any jar by mistake in the classpath hence no warning should come.

#### Option 2  see my anwer:

[spark-submit-jars-arguments-wants-comma-list-how-to-declare-a-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35550151/647053)

#### Option 3 : If you want to do programmatic submit by adding jars through API its possible.Here Im not going to details of it.

Comment: was it helpful? your resource jar as well you can copy to that folder

Comment: spark-submit --driver-class-path adam_2.11-0.20.0.jar --class com.ano.adam.AnnoSp myApp1.jar works for spark2.0.1