# External jars lib with spark-submit

Tags: jar, hdfs, spark-submit

I have a scala app which uses an external jar lib. How can I use it if the application jar was copied to hdfs?

From local I was start with `--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=./lib/*` but if I use hdfs link it will not work.

Comment: Why don't you just build a fat jar using maven https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven ? The same thing is available for gradle or other build tool

Comment: @jojo_Berlin that good case, but I not need all libs.

Comment: @user5730669: check my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40797172/647053)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to append a resource jar for spark-submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796818/how-to-append-a-resource-jar-for-spark-submit)

Comment: @jojo_Berlin I was created fat jar. But it not good issue because in result I had big jar file, wich will copy on all nodes when jar is running. After developing application I will create oozie and upload all lib with oozie from external lib on HDFS.