# How to save pyspark dataframe from hive into iginte cache?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, ignite

I would like to save my pyspark dataframe into ignite cache following the approach from this [blog](https://medium.com/@sdarlington/the-trick-to-successfully-integrating-apache-ignite-and-pyspark-890e436d09ba), but some error happened.
Error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_ignite.py", line 19, in <module>
    .option("config", configFile) \
  File "/home/hdoop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 738, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "/home/hdoop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/hdoop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/hdoop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: ignite. Please find packages at
http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
       
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:443)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:720)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.lookupV2Provider(DataFrameWriter.scala:852)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:247)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ignite.DefaultSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:656)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:656)
        at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:656)
        ... 16 more
```

These are my steps:

1. I executed a Python script. `python3 test_ignite.py`
2. Created a SparkSession and connected to hive.
3. Tried to get a Pyspark dataframe from hive.
4. Saved it to the ignite cache. (error occurred)

My **test_ignite.py** code is:

```
import os
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyignite import Client

spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("consumer_hive") \
.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083") \
.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/usr/local/ignite/libs/*jar:/usr/local/ignite/libs/optional/ignite-spark/*jar:/usr/local/ignite/libs/ignite-spring/*jar:/usr/local/ignite/libs/ignite-indexing/*jar") \
.enableHiveSupport() \
.getOrCreate()

df = spark.sql("select * from hive_table")

configFile = os.environ['IGNITE_HOME'] + "config/default-config.xml"

df.write.format("ignite") \
            .option("table", "TickData") \
            .option("config", configFile) \
            .save()
```

I have found the same issue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56372007/), but the error still exists after adding the **spark.driver.extraClassPath**.
Should I set any config or setting because I never modify **/ignite/config/default-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
    -->
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration"/>
</beans>
```

My Spark config:

**spark-defaults.conf**

```
spark.master spark://pc1-vm1:7077
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir hdfs://pc1-vm1:9000/user/hdoop/log
spark.serializer org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.driver.memory 4g
spark.executor.memory 6g
spark.executor.cores 2
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors 2
spark.ui.enabled true


spark.driver.extraClassPath /usr/local/ignite/libs/*jar:/usr/local/ignite/libs/optional/ignite-spark/*jar:/usr/local/ignite/libs/ignite-spring/*jar:/usr/local/ignite/libs/ignite-indexing/*jar
```

**spark-env.sh**

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/lib/scala
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=pc1-vm1
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=32G
export SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=4G
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop classpath)
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH='hadoop classpath'
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HBASE_CLASSPATH
export HIVE_HOME=/home/hadoop/hive 
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=$HIVE_HOME/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:$SPARK_CLASSPATH
```

These are the version I used:

```
- Hadoop v2.10.1
- Spark v2.3.4
- Hive v2.1.1
- Python v3.7.5
- openjdk-8-jre
- Ignite v2.7
```

Could anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need ignite JARs on the *executor* classpath, so `spark.driver.extraClassPath` should probably be `spark.executor.extraClassPath`, but you should rather use `spark-submit --packages` flag to add `spark-ignite` library

Alternatively, the docs mention that you can modify `spark-env.sh` to add Ignite libraries to `SPARK_CLASSPATH` (which you've not done)

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/ignite-for-spark/installation

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, thank you for your reply.
I have added the spark.executor.extraClassPath in both SparkSession config of python script and spark.defaults.conf, and modify spark-env.sh following the docs.
Then, I tried to execute `/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.ignite:ignite-spark:2.7.6  test_ignite.py`. It seems to work, but I got another error, which is `pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: "Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':"`

Comment: The issue occurred when I used spark-submit to run my script instead of using python3. Do your have any suggestion about it?

Comment: You definitely should use Spark submit... I've not used ignite, but I suggest verifying that version v2.3.4 of Spark is compatible with the version of the package you're using

Comment: @Po-Hao Liao - have u managed to solve this error? Im getting exactly same error