# Unable to read Hbase data with spark in yarn cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hbase, cloudera-cdh

Cluster configuration:

- Hadoop: CDH-6.2.1
- Spark: 2.4.0
- Hbase: 2.0

What I do: Read HBase data through Spark

When I use IntelliJ and `local` mode everything works fine, but when I change mode to
`spark-submit --master yarn`, the following stacktrace happens:

```
20/05/20 11:00:46 ERROR mapreduce.TableInputFormat: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.initialize(TableInputFormat.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.getSplits(TableInputFormat.java:254)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at com.song.HbaseOnSpark1$.main(HbaseOnSpark1.scala:32)
    at com.song.HbaseOnSpark1.main(HbaseOnSpark1.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:673)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:219)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.close(ConnectionImplementation.java:1938)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionImplementation.java:310)
    ... 32 more

20/05/20 11:00:46 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot create a record reader because of a previous error. Please look at the previous logs lines from the task's full log for more details.
java.io.IOException: Cannot create a record reader because of a previous error. Please look at the previous logs lines from the task's full log for more details.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.getSplits(TableInputFormat.java:254)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at com.song.HbaseOnSpark1$.main(HbaseOnSpark1.scala:32)
    at com.song.HbaseOnSpark1.main(HbaseOnSpark1.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:673)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The input format instance has not been properly initialized. Ensure you call initializeTable either in your constructor or initialize method
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getTable(TableInputFormatBase.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:249)
    ... 24 more
```

This is my code:

```
 val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark1")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)

    val hbaseConf: Configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","hadoop01,hadoop02,hadoop03")
    hbaseConf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE,"idx_name")
    hbaseConf.set("hbase.defaults.for.version.skip", "true")


    val rdd: RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Result)] = spark.newAPIHadoopRDD(
      hbaseConf,
      classOf[TableInputFormat],
      classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
      classOf[Result]
    )
```

Comment: thought it was a problem of htrace-core jar conflict, but no solution was found

Comment: A few days have passed, still no solution found, can someone help me? >3<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its hbase classpatth issue in your cluster   but you need to add hbase jars to your classpath like this

```
 export SPARK_CLASSPATH=$SPARK_CLASSPATH:`hbase classpath`
```

`hbase classpath` will give all the jars for hbase connections and etc....

#### Why its working in local mode ?

*Since all the jars required are there in ide lib*

---

If you are using maven do a `mvn depdency:tree` to understand what jars are needed in the cluster. based on that you can adjust your `spark-submit` script.

if you are using `--jars` option see that all jars passed correctly or uber jar has correct dependencies when packing jar..

#### *There might be jar conflict also check that carefully with local mode environment since thats working fine.*

Further reading [Spark spark-submit --jars arguments wants comma list, how to declare a directory of jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738296/spark-spark-submit-jars-arguments-wants-comma-list-how-to-declare-a-directory/35550151#35550151)

Comment: Hi,i have try what u said,but is not solved，If you have other suggestions, please let me know, thanks

Comment: It's not like random suggestions show me your spark-submit in cluster mode and your classpath of hbase

Comment: There might be network issue as well which is hard to debug  from here

Comment: Forget about suggestions what is the difference in classpath you found  between local and yarn add into questions as update

Comment: Now I found the same problem when connecting to phoenix in the same way, anyway, thank you for your detailed recovery, thank you

Comment: finally，copy lib/hbase/*.jar and lib/hbase/lib/*.jar to lib/spark/jars/，all be resolved,so this should be a enviroment issue,thanks for your help again.