# Use JAR Files In Bash

Tags: java, linux, bash, ssh, jar

I've been looking for an answer, but still a little confused...

In eclipse I just configure the build path of the project and add the jar files that I need, and everything works just fine. When I try to run my programs via Bash, it's not finding my imports.

How do I run my Java programs in bash or on another server with the required jar files?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify the `CLASSPATH`. Either through the environment like

```
export CLASSPATH="a.jar:b.jar"
java com.stackoverflow.Main
```

or explicitly via the `-cp` command line option like,

```
java -cp a.jar:b.jar com.stackoverflow.Main
```

Comment: I just call export CLASSPATH="a.jar:b.jar" in the same directory my java programs are?

Comment: You have to put the path to `a.jar` and `b.jar` if they're in different directories from your java programs.

Comment: I cant just add an entire folder of jar files all at once? It seems very unintuitive to add them all individually.

Comment: @Dylan See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729863/using-bash-how-do-you-make-a-classpath-out-of-all-files-in-a-directory).

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Interesting, I added the jar files to the class path and it worked. A few hours later I tried it again and I'm getting an error that the packages I'm trying to import are not found. Did the exact same thing and made no changes...

Comment: Make sure your CLASSPATH is set as you expect (perhaps `echo` it) and check the jars are actually in the folder you're specifying.

Comment: I did echo ${CLASSPATH} and it looks correct. one of the 6 files in the path are ./required_jar_files/gs-algo-1.3-javadoc.jar: and I'm using this command: CLASSPATH=$(find "." -name '*.jar' | xargs echo | tr ' ' ':'):.

Comment: @Dylan Why? From that linked question, you want `java -cp "./required_jar_files/*"`

Comment: Still no luck. echo cp is correct. Would it be possible for us to chat?

Comment: I don't really have time for chat right now, but make sure you're in the correct folder (since you're using relative paths).