# Print the Java Classpath on macOS (Mac OS X)

Tags: java, macos, classpath

On the command-line, how can I see all the folders and files comprising my current [Java classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29)?

The [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) says to use `echo $CLASSPATH` on Unix-like systems. But on a Mac (El Capitan) with Java 8 that prints nothing. As I recall, by default the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is not used on macOS.

I saw some Questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729863/using-bash-how-do-you-make-a-classpath-out-of-all-files-in-a-directory/4729899#4729899) that show *setting* the classpath, but I just want to *verify* the classpath.

Is there some easy way from the command-line to examine the current classpath?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you explicitly set the `CLASSPATH` variable in either the current shell or in your login profile (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`), then there is no way to show what it is.

> If you don't have the CLASSPATH set, then the default value of the
>   class path is ".", meaning that only the current directory is
>   searched. Specifying either the CLASSPATH variable or the -cp command
>   line switch overrides this value.

Comment: I suspect you are confusing the environment variable `CLASSPATH` with the Java Classpath feature. The variable is one way to specify the classpath, but does *not* define the classpath in its entirety. On the Mac, for example, the variable is not used at all by default while there is still an active classpath that includes multiple files and folders.

Comment: For anyone wanting a source for this answer. Here it is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html It says: "The default is the current directory to conveniently enable those classes to be found."

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if $CLASSPATH is available in OSX by default.  But, `$PATH` might help you.  This variable has the information about the directories that contain executable commands.

Comment: The question is about the [Java Classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) only, not all executables.

Answer (score 3):

In Java Code, using below helps to differentiate easily:
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));        System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.boot.class.path"));

Answer (score 1):

In your java code do:

```
System.out.println(System.class.path);
```

This lists all the classpaths to the jar files (java platform classes), the class path for your project, etc. The classpaths are separated by semicolons. Michael Markidis is right about "If you don't have the CLASSPATH set, then the default value of the class path is ".", meaning that only the current directory is searched." And you should find that in this list.

> When classes are stored in a directory (folder), such as c:\java\MyClasses\utility\myapp, then the class path entry points to the directory that contains the first element of the package name (in this case, C:\java\MyClasses, because the package name is utility.myapp).

So if you use packages, the ending directory of your applications class path should be your root package.

Comment: This no longer compiles